# Problems with quad in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, numerical-integration

Can someone explain, why:

```
from sympy.mpmath import quad
x, y = symbols('x y')
f, g = symbols('f g', cls=Function)
f = x
g = x+1
u_1 = lambda x: f + g
quad(u_1,[-1,1])
```

gives a mistake and

```
from sympy.mpmath import quad
x, y = symbols('x y')
f, g = symbols('f g', cls=Function)
f = x
g = x+1
u_1 = lambda x: x + x+1
quad(u_1,[-1,1])
```

works fine?
How to make first version works right?

Answer (score 3):

```
lambda x: f + g
```

This is a function that takes in `x` and returns the sum of two values **that do not depend on `x`**. Whatever values f and g were before they stay that value.

```
lambda x: x + x + 1
```

This is a function that returns the input value `x` as `x+x+1`. This function *will* depend on the input.

In python, unlike mathematics, when you evaluate the series of commands

```
a = 1
b = a
a = 2
```

the value of `b` is `1`.